# How do you handle debugging when using Prototype.js

Tags: debugging, error-handling, prototypejs

In a lot of cases when my prototype.js javascript code hits an error, I don't get any error notification, line number, etc. I usually end up tracing through my code with alert statement until I find where it dies. Is there a better way to track down these errors?

Comment: I have the same problem — I don't even see 'throw' output with Prototype in Firebug, *but* everything is fine in Chrome.

Comment: @Dustin I totally agree. Sometimes, it is a nightmare trying to debug prototype.js classes. Errors do not always show up in FF console. Today, I proved that an exception was being thrown, but no clues in FF console. I am going to put in try() blocks:                                                   try {
    
}
catch(err) {
    console.log(err.message);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on browser, but there are some very good ways of handling errors. If you are using firefox, you can install FireBug and then use:

```
console.log('like an alert but in the firebug window');
```

It's alot quicker than pressing ok, then ok, then ok...

http://getfirebug.com/

Firebug also has an amazing JS error debugger, and gives great feedback as to what is wrong with your code. A must have if you ask me!

Comment: Thanks. I already use Firebug for this purpose but there are a lot of times when my js code won't do anything (no errors - just failure) because of a typo or something and because of the scale of the code I'm working on I end up spending way too much time tracking it down. I was looking for a better way to handle problems like this.

Comment: Generally under the console pane in Firebug it will let you see the point at which it has failed. You can also use break points to move through the code. Have you tried these?

Comment: Not sure why this answer was accepted, as it does not answer the question. Firebug 'console' does not show run time errors when using (at least this version of) Prototype.js.

Comment: @leegee The question wasn't why does it not show the errors, it was what is a better way to debug. Using console.log is a much better way to debug code than using an alert (as mentioned).

Comment: @sparkyfied See his comment above yours, about already using Firebug. His problem, it seems, is that Firebug doesn't actually log the actual errors — which I find Chrome does, even when FF does not.

Answer (score 0):

> I already use Firebug ...

Is this case, try Chrome — I find that Firefox fails to notify me of errors in my code that uses Prototype.js, but Chrome is fine. Not that I'm a huge fan of Google over Mozilla.